# RSA Encryption - Public Key Encryption

Tags: encryption, key, rsa, public

I would like to use RSA encryption on a large file (>25 MB).
Is it possible or are there limitations using a Public Key/Private Key for a large app?
I am exposing a public key to clients and not allowing anyone but the recipient to view the contents with the private key. So the business case makes sense although it will be slower than symmetrical encryption.

Thanks,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: 25MB is not a large file. This is not the 1980s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA cannot encrypt a payload larger than its key size (minus some overhead for padding). To bypass this limitation you'll need to generate a symmetric key, use that to encrypt the larger file, then encrypt the symmetric key itself with RSA (with OAEP or PKCS1v1.5 padding).

Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) and PKCS7 (CMS's predecessor) support this use case already so there's no need to invent your own protocol.

Comment: Nice and clear explanation of the concepts involved. An up vote from me.